# Mongo advanced operations on querying data

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

This table below is structured in my mongo object as the code below:

| Element 1 | Element 2 | Element 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 23 | 89 | 7 |
| 12 | 6 | 33 |

```
id: "blabla",
header: [
  {name: Element 1},
  {name: Element 2}
  {name: Element 3}
],
rows: [
  [23,89,7],
  [12,6,33]
]
```

What I am trying to achieve here is find every object in my collection where "Element 2" has a value equal to 89.

I am aware that with pipelines you could get the index where that "Element 2" is so later I could query the rows only at that exact index. The latter is what I am having difficulty to understand how it is done.
I really could use some help or some resources since I have never worked with mongo before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who has the same question it's been 3 days and i have managed to achieve what i wanted via this pipeline array

```
var pipeline = [
    { $match: {"header": { "$elemMatch": { "name": "Element 1" } } } },
    {
        $unwind: {
            "path":"$header",
            includeArrayIndex: "_index"
        }
    },
    { $match: {"header.name": "Element 1" } },
    {
        $unwind: {
            "path":"$rows",
        }
    },
    {
         $project:
          {
             val: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$rows", "$_index" ] },
          }
    },
    { $match: {"val": {$lte : 13.3} } },
]
```